# Scope when using Event Handlers and Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, reflection

I have a `Button` defined in Xaml like

```xml
<Button Name="button1" />
```

I'm trying to subscribe to the `Click` event of this `Button` using Reflection. More precisely I want to invoke an `Action<object, EventArgs>` and inside the event handler I want to access a local variable from outside of the scope like this

```
string testString = "Hello";
Action<object, EventArgs> clickAction = (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(testString);
};
```

If I do this, `Hello` is displayed

```
clickAction.Invoke(null, null);
```

Similar, if I just subscribe to the `Click` event like this, `Hello` is displayed

```
button1.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
    MessageBox.Show(testString);
};
```

But if I use reflection to subscribe to the event with `AddEventHandler`, I'm unable to access `testString` and I get a `NullReferenceException` in the event handler.

```
Type buttonType = button1.GetType();
EventInfo clickEvent = buttonType.GetEvent("Click");
Delegate clickEventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(clickEvent.EventHandlerType,
                                                     null,
                                                     clickAction.Method);
clickEvent.AddEventHandler(button1, clickEventHandler);
```

- Why does this happend?
- Is there a fix I can apply to make it work the way I want?
- Do I have another option?

---

### Update - This is what the Method looks like in full

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    string testString = "Hello";
    Action<object, EventArgs> clickAction = (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(testString);
    };

    Type buttonType = button1.GetType();
    EventInfo clickEvent = buttonType.GetEvent("Click");
    Delegate clickEventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(clickEvent.EventHandlerType,
                                                         null,
                                                         clickAction.Method);
    clickEvent.AddEventHandler(button1, clickEventHandler);
}
```

Comment: where is `teststring` defined ? is it a local variable ? a class member ? a static ?

Comment: @Yahia: It is at the beginning of the post, it is a local variable and it is defined above the `Action`

Comment: @Yahia: Updated the question with the full method

Comment: I suspect that `teststring` being local this is the reason you get that error... one option I can think of is making it static...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - rewriting my answer after the comments:

you can make this work if you bind the delegate to an instance. that instance should be a class containing all information/variable you want to use from within your event handler...
you create that instance, initialize it with the values you want and then bind it:

```
Delegate clickEventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(clickEvent.EventHandlerType, yourinstance, clickAction.Method);
```

this way the delegate has a "this" which can be used to access the variables...
you could even make those variables instead of local just plain class fields and bind the delegate to `this`.

another option would be to put thos variables into the "sender object" and access them that way...

Comment: But I only get the problem when I'm using reflection, if I just subscribe to the event it works fine. I can't use a static variable since this method will be called many times and I need to keep track of other variables inside the event handler

Comment: +1, Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, in my real scenario, this method belongs to the `PropertyChangedCallback` of an attached property so the method is static.. I tried to send `this` (being `MainWindow`) in my test application but got a binding exception

Comment: just an idea - not sure whether this would work in your case: instead of assigning a Click handler assign a command (which itself is a class with the ability to contain additional information/field...)